# Codeigniter 3.0.6 log file doesn't show 404 Page not found

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the latest CodeIgniter framework, for some reason when the visitors visits a page not found (404), it gets logged in the log file as follow:

```
ERROR - 2016-05-01 20:51:27 --> 404 Page Not Found: 
ERROR - 2016-05-01 20:51:28 --> 404 Page Not Found:
```

As you can seen It doesn't show what was the page visited to check where is the break or the visitors is physically visiting a wrong page.

I might made a stupid mistake in one of the files that made it not recording the pages that got visited.

Any idea?

Comment: show your controller name & code for which user getting 404 error

Comment: any controller or method that doesn't exist, it shows a page not found which is correct, but in the log it shows only 404 Page Not Found: (empty xxxx/xxxxx)